# Waston Conversation: pass conversation to email?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

**GOAL:**
To hand the conversation off to a real person.

**PROBLEM:**
Rather than just saying something like "*I don't know*" when a customer asks a question which our Conversation is not programmed to answer (or doesn't recognize), we would much rather pass the question to a live representative.

While passing the conversation to SMS or phone might be options, EMAIL is certainly our preference.

**QUESTION:**
How do I do this?
What's the starting point?

**BTW:**
I ***have*** looked for tutorials/examples/how-to's, and maybe there are better search terms that those I've thought of so far, but my many google attempts have come up empty.

Answer (score 1):

Watson Conversation service is an independent service, i.e. it isn't aware of any other service or module that the application is interacting or communicating with. But you can modify and use the response from the Conversation service to trigger particular functionality that you might need in your application, for your case **trigger an Email**. I have done some similar work recently, whereupon activating a particular dialog in Conversation, it will ask you to share your email Id and after that, it activates the *"send email"* flow in the application. We have our Conversation dialog something like this for this case. You need to do this on the JSON editor of the dialog node in Conversation.

```
 {
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Please hold while I validate and send you an email as requested"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    },
    "user_operation": {
      "operation_type": "product_email",
      "selection_type": "custom"
    }
  }
}
```

Once you get this response in your application, you can parse it and retrieve what operation is intended in the *user_operation* attribute of the received response. In this case, it'll be to send a product email to the user(considering you already have the user's email id with you)

```
"user_operation": {
      "operation_type": "product_email",
      "selection_type": "custom"
    }
```

You can then have a block of code in your application that will actually send the Email to the customer and once it's done, you can simply send a dummy predefined text like "Success" or something to Conversation service that will trigger the next node in the flow.